# (Suspended) REASONS for Firebase Hosting with create-react-app error: 1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, 2. White Blank Page in Hosting URL

Tags: reactjs, firebase, browser, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

I want your help for giving TECHNICAL reasons for the issues and it's solutions I found in my personal project.
The issue happens when Deploying my app with Firebase CLI Tools.

- My App is made with create-react-app.

My questions is: Why do the Issue.1 and Issue.2 underneath happen?

I want to know the TECHNICAL REASONS based on technical FACTS, but I'm also grateful if you let me know the possible technical FIELD.
I'm thinking it might be because of the process of Deploying like Bundling or something which I do not know at all.

- The SOLUTION for BOTH issue is setting the build Folder (Instead of public Folder) as the Public Directory.
- Take care of the DIFFERENT URL where the issue happens (Localhost 3000 or Hosting URL).

...
Issue.1 = In localhost 3000, an Error Message Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < is sent.

- What I did

1. In CLI, Deploy with Firebase CLI

: Set the public Folder as the App public Folder.

: Deploy from firebase init Command.

: Answer NO for ACTIVATING the REWRITES.

: Answer Yes for OVERWRITING the index.html

: Answer Yes for OVERWRITING the 404.html

: npm run deploy Shortcut Command (npm run build + firebase deploy).

- Possible cause: I see this Issue happens when setting the public Folder  (Instead of build Folder) as Public Directory in the Firebase CLI process.
- [Pic.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEdMB.png) = Issue.1/In CLI, the process after firebase init.
- [Pic.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOFdV.jpg) = Issue.1/App Directory & public/index.html/Tops of added contents by firebase init
- [Pic.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajbt6.png) = Issue.1/Localhost 3000
- [Pic.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAKD1.png) = Issue.1/Hosting Page

...
Issue.2 = In the Hosting URL the UI is Blank

- What I did

1. In public/index.html

: Delete all the contents added by firebase init Command.

: Add `<div id="root">`

2. In CLI, Deploy with Firebase CLI

: npm run deploy Shortcut Command.

- Possible cause:  I see this Issue happens when 1. setting the public Folder  (Instead of build Folder) as Public Directory 2. Activating OVERWRITING the public/index.html File in the Firebase CLI process.
- [Pic.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1DPW.png) = Issue.2/App Directory & public/index.html
- [Pic.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4oNE.png) = Issue.2/Hosting Page
- [Pic.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djwuu.png) =  Issue.2/Localhost 3000 (Proof for the solution of Issue.1 by DELETING the ADDED contents in public/index.html by firebase init Command).

...
The Solution Case.

- The build Folder as the Public Directory would be the solution.
- What I did

1. In CLI, Deploy with Firebase CLI

: Set the build Folder as the App public Folder.

: Deploy from firebase init Command.

: Answer Yes for ACTIVATING the REWRITES.

: Answer Yes for OVERWRITING the build/index.html

: Answer Yes for OVERWRITING the build/404.html

: npm run deploy Shortcut Command.

...

- Firebase CLI Tools Version (By firebase -V): 9.1.0
- GitHub Repo: https://github.com/Nobu-sai/commitment-record/tree/issue-1
- The time I can mainly reply: From 14:00-15:00 .p.m (JST, GMT+9)

...

Please let me know if further information is needed.

I appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: A relevant issue to Issue.1 and the reason by a developer. (Would be Vanila JS and Firebase Hosting)
(https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/899#issuecomment-417717469)
This is usually due to your webpage referencing a JS file that doesn't exist, and your rewrite rules serving up an HTML page at the JS file's location. Make sure that your <script src> tag is properly referencing the relative/absolute path of your JS file.

Comment: Please do not mind how long passed from the date I asked this question. 
As long as I obviously conclude this, I’m await for the answer. 
Now I’m going to suspend this for now to focus on learning react. 
Have a good day.